# Get value of a variable from url

Tags: odoo

Odoo 11.0

Is there a way to get the variable "model" from the url? I need it to know in which module the user are.

For example:
localhost:8069/web#page=0&view_type=list&model=my.module&menu_id=167&action=501

Some idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try `self.model` or `self._context.get('active_model')`

Comment: You're mixing `module` and `model` here. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry is the model. I've a model of vehicles, this model is filtered based on the logged user 'cause he  can only see those vehicles linked to him. Vehicles are linked to users under the user form in settings and there the vehicle model must returns all vehicles. I need to know if the user are in the vehicle model or the user model to apply the filter or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

params.get('model');
```

Comment: thanks but I need to do it in python under Odoo environment

Answer (score 0):

```
from openerp.http import Controller, route, request, Response

class YourControllerName(Controller):
    @route('/your_module/your_route', auth='public')
    def index(self, *args, **kw):
        if request.httprequest.method == 'GET' and request.session.uid and request.params.get('model'):
            return "Model: %s"%request.params.get('model')
        else:
            return "Hello, world"
```